# nodenv: version `8.9.1' is not installed

Tags: npm, npm-start

I am trying to run my React project by `npm start` but get following error.

```
nodenv: version `8.9.1' is not installed 
(set by /Users/xyz/github-repos/react/.node-version)
```

Comment: what version of node are you using

Comment: Is there a specific version required in your package.json?

Comment: @a0js it's showing Node 8.9.1 only.

Comment: When you run ‘node -v’ what result do you get?

Comment: It gives following error: `nodenv: version 8.9.1 is not installed (set by /Users/xyz/github-repos/react/.node-version)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A oneliner solution might be:

```
nodenv install $(cat .node-version)
```

- print the version specified in `.node-version`
- use that as input for the `nodenv install` command

If your environment is setup correctly, there is no need to redefine the local version with `nodenv local`. The version is already saved in the aforementioned `.node-version` file.

You would run `nodenv local <version>` on the first system where you define the project's `nodejs` version to write the preferred `nodejs` version to `.node-version`.

Running `yarn` or `yarn install` is not part of the requirements to run the correct `nodejs` version in the project's directory. Running `yarn` will install the dependencies specified in `package.json`.

Answer (score 4):

on mac I had to first do

```
brew upgrade nodenv node-build
```

then I could do

```
nodenv install 8.9.1
nodenv local 8.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following commands fixed my problem

```
nodenv install 8.9.1
nodenv local 8.9.1
yarn install
```